# how to apply skins to user controls in devExpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have replaced DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm with my normal window forms and registered userskins. so far so good. (I can see the skins and also apply them to all forms.) But my application also uses user controls, so i also replaced it with  DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl. But however i couldnt see the skins applying to my user controls. I am missing some refernces.. ?

Additional Info:

1. I have got right dll's in my reference folder.
2. I have referred in the usercontrol class (using DevExpress.XtraEditors;)
3. I have changed System.Windows.Forms.UserControl to  DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl

Comment: I have test my application and found that themes or skins cannot apply to win tabcontrols. So how can i convert windows tabcontrol/tabpages to devxpress tab pages inorder to see my themes.

Comment: Care to accept your answers that help to solve problem.. Otherwise delete your question if it is not a real question

Answer (score 0):

follow the DevExpress forum link: [Apply LookAndFeel style to custom UserControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q261630.aspx)

Ref:
[How to get colors that correspond to the currently used skin](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/AK9476.aspx)
[How to obtain the color of a particular control's element when skins are used](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A2967.aspx)

Comment: Hi Niranjan, I have test my application and found that themes or skins cannot apply to win tabcontrols. So how can i convert windows tabcontrol/tabpages to devxpress tab pages inorder to see my themes.

Comment: check this [search result](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/SearchResults.aspx#cD1UNHxQMXwwc2VhcmNodGV4dD1hcHBseSBza2luIHRvIHN0YW5kYXJkIHdpbmZvcm1zIGNvbnRyb2w=), it may be helpful to you.. update me if it work or not..